# Javascript string array to multiple strings separated by a comma

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

How can i convert a string array to output a single string, separated by a comma.

Convert `["Red", "Blue", "Green"]` 
To this `"Red", "Blue", "Green"`

I am **NOT** looking for a comma-separated list of strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `join` and pre-/post-fix a couple of extra quotes.

```js
var arr = ["Red", "Blue", "Green"];
var out = '"' + arr.join('", "') + '"';
console.log(out);
```

Or using a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```js
var arr = ["Red", "Blue", "Green"];
var out = `"${arr.join('", "')}"`;
console.log(out);
```

Comment: nice, I think this is what he is looking for, never thought of it that way!

Comment: This was exactly what i was looking for, thanks.

Sorry others if i was bad at explaining it.

I will mark it as correct answer as soon as five minutes has passed.

Thanks guys

Comment: It's super hacky, and won't work as expected, you'll get `""Red", "Blue", "Green""` a strings inside a string, lol.

Comment: Well, it was exactly what the OP was looking for, so I don't know what your point is. @AlexanderKim

Answer (score 0):

More elegant way, using `map` and ES6:

```js
const arr = ['str1', 'str2', 'str3', 'str4']
console.log(arr.map(v => `'${v}'`).join(','))
```